# Get parameters of .js file

Tags: javascript, parameters, filenames

I have a javascript file that I reference in HTML with standard `<script src="foo.js?param"></script>`. In the file I want to distinguish e.g. loading the file with `foo.js` from `foo.js?auto` and `foo.js?noauto=true`, but not if the file is renamed to `bar.js` and referenced with the same parameter. How can I accomplish this, preferably not using any framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954099/help-me-to-understand-script-srcsome-jsparam1oneparam2two

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look a scriptaculous' approach:

```
var js = /scriptaculous\.js(\?.*)?$/;
$$('head script[src]').findAll(function(s) {
  return s.src.match(js);
}).each(function(s) {
  var path = s.src.replace(js, ''),
  includes = s.src.match(/\?.*load=([a-z,]*)/);
  (includes ? includes[1] : 'builder,effects,dragdrop,controls,slider,sound').split(',').each(
   function(include) { Scriptaculous.require(path+include+'.js') });
});
```

I think it runs through all script elements and finds the reference to itself, and then parses that URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it reliably, then you need to provide different JS for each URL. You could generate it with a server side script.

If you want to do it in pure JS, then you can `getElementsByTagName('script')` and assume that last script is the one that matched (it might not be, e.g. if script elements are being added using DOM after the page has loaded).

Comment: Good idea, but I guess I should warn users not to change the name of the included file or call some method in case of explicit execution on load of body.