# how to set a variable for external javascript file?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I am trying to figure out how to set my session_id variable to to be used in an external js file. Here is what I have.

php file:

```
$output = '<script src="test.js">
     var session_id = '.$_SESSION['id'].'
</script>';
print $output;
```

js file:

```
alert(session_id);
```

With this I am getting an error saying session_id is not defined. Is there a way to pass this info across?

I know I could just setup a hidden input with the info but I am thinking there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: No matter how you generate it, the resulting text must be valid JavaScript code: compare alert(session_id) with alert("session_id")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum, what about:

```
$output = '<script type="text/javascript> var session_id = '.$_SESSION['id'].'</script><script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>';
print $output;
```

?

Comment: Small typo: remove the "." behind $_SESION['id'] and use $_SESSION['id'] instead of $_SESION['id'] ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're including an external JS file, you can't put code between the script tags.  So you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var session_id = <?php print $_SESSION['id']; ?>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Though you could get around this kludginess by making the session ID a hidden form field in your HTML and then using DOM methods in test.js to find it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can deal with session_id as a global variable, then the following will do it:

```
<script>
     var session_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>'
</script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

If you want to make the variable only available to the javascript file in a closure etc. you can send the js file through the PHP parser or use parameters for your js file, but the latter is not really easily accessible from javascript, see [my question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221564/get-parameters-of-js-file).

Answer (score 0):

The content within the `<script>` tag is only executed if the JavaScript file is *not* found. Set your variables in a separate `<script>` tag before that has no file set:

```
<script>
     var session_id = '<?=$_SESSION['id']?>';
</script>
<script src="test.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to have PHP serve a script like this:

- Have a JS file prepared with the variable definitions you require:

```
var value1 = '{value1}';
var value2 = '{value2}';

...
// script goes here
```

- With PHP, read the file and replace the `{value1}` and `{value2}` tags with your data:

```
if ($_GET["script"])
{
 $data = array(
   "value1" => $_SESSION["id"],    # i.e.
   "value2" => $foo
 );

 $script = file_get_contents($script . ".js");

 foreach ($data as $key => $value)
 {
  $script = str_replace("{" . $key . "}", $value, $script);
 }

 header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
 echo $script;
 exit();
}
```

- Then you can call your PHP "parser" like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="?script=myscript"></script>
```