# how to set a variable for external javascript file after the js file is defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Mobile Ajax navigation feature, And I need to change a variable that is defined inside external js file, So I **can't** put my definition **before** I load that js file...

So, How to change value of a variable for external javascript file after the js file is defined?

(That external js file includes events)

---

*So this question is **not** duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2357472/942659).*

---

### Update

My JS File contains events, something like this: `$(document).on('mousemove','#main',function() { /*something*/} );`

And I need that variable. Is it possible to pass variable to that?

I have tried simply changing that variable `i = 5;`, but I'm getting undefined error.

---

### Update 2

The external JS file is something for some pages that are almost same, but a little different, just one or two parameters.

And I simply want to pass the parameters to that JS file. Is it possible? How?

Comment: It depends. `variable = 'value';` could work

Comment: @zerkms I tried it, but didn't work... (Still getting `undefined` error)

Comment: that's why I said "it depends", because it really depends on what and how you do in that external file.

Comment: Question updated. What other information should I put on the question?

Comment: If it's out of scope, it's out of scope, period!

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi "*And I need that variable*" Which variable is that? If you mean `i`, as `i = 5` would suggest, and it's declared as `var i` where `/*something*/` is currently, then it's a local variable only accessible within that `function`. No other file will be able to alter it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Oh! I have putted variable declarations inside `$(document).ready(...`! Thank you very much...

Comment: Still I don't know Why this question is -2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume `http://www.example.com/external.js` defines variable `foo`, which you want to change.

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/external.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    foo = "my new value";
</script>
```

This assumes that external.js defined `foo` in the global scope.  If it's defined in an anonymous function or similar, you won't be able to change the value.

Comment: *If it's defined in an anonymous function or similar, you won't be able to change the value.* Thanks for it!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing, you can just set the variable and it'll work. Example:

```
// JS file
blah = "Hello";
function doSomething() {
    alert(blah);
}

// HTML file
blah = "I'm a fish";
doSomething(); // alerts "I'm a fish";
```

Alternatively, pass the variable as an argument to relevant functions instead of using global variables.