# javascript get Value

Tags: javascript, get, url-parameters

code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/Test.js#username=stackoverflow">
</script>
```

iwant to know ,how to get the username in Test.js

file
Test.js :

```
var username =  ??

///////////// #username=stackoverflow
```

thanks advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do all this on the client side, it's much better to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    var username = "stackoverflow";
//]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/Test.js"></script>
```

That way, you don't need to tackle the issue of reading the `src` attribute of the script tag somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The query portion of the URL is invalid. It should be:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Test.js?username=stackoverflow
```

The `#` is treated as a named anchor.

Answer (score 0):

The gup function isn't good because the parameter is on the script tag, not the HTML output page.

The *location* object (location.href, location.search...)  refers to the HTML page where the script included.

There are 2 other options:

1. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221564/get-parameters-of-js-file)
2. **Use @idealmachine answer.** You can wrap the global variable with simple object in order to avoid conflict with other global JS variables

Comment: Read about object oriented and objects in JS: http://www.webreference.com/js/column79/

And about *location* object: http://w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: The gup function explained here: http://efreedom.com/Question/1-3582390/Get-URL-Parameters-JS-Embed-JS-Function


The answer that mention it was deleted